# Install different PHP packages based on hosts groups

Tags: loops, ansible

I am creating a simple playbook and in my host file, I have a `webserver` group and a `backoffice` group. I want to install different PHP modules to the different groups via the playbook. The below code doesn't pick up the `when` condition and runs for both groups.

Is it possible to add a `when` condition within `with_items` or filter with the loop function?

Even this is not applying the when condition:

```yaml
- package: "{{ backoffice_php82_modules }}"
  when: "'aaa' =='bbb'"
```

The hosts file:

```yaml
all:
  vars:
  children:
    backoffice:
      hosts:
        backoffice1:
          ansible_host: 10.1.1.2
```

The playbook:

```yaml
- name: Install PHP modules
  hosts: all
  vars:
    backoffice_php82_modules:
    - php82
    - php82-php-fpm
    - php82-php-bcmath
    webserver_php82_modules:
    - php82
    - php82-php-fpm
    - php82-php-amqp
  tasks:
    - name: Install PHP modules
      yum: name={{ item.package }} state=present enablerepo=remi-php82,remi-safe,epel
      with_items:
        - package: "{{ backoffice_php82_modules }}"
          when: "'backoffice' in group_names"
        - package: "{{ webserver_php82_modules }}"
          when: "'webserver' in group_names "
```

Answer (score 2):

To build up on β.εηοιτ.βε's answer, you can go a step further and:

1. manage common and specific packages for your groups.
2. apply good practice to the `yum` module usage by dropping the loop and installing all packages at once

For the first point, the inventory and its vars would look like the following:

*Note: `d([])` which is an alias for `default([])` is there to make sure nothing breaks if a specific group does not have any custom modules defined.*

```yaml
all:
  vars:
    php_common_modules:
      - php82
      - php82-php-fpm
    php_modules: "{{ php_common_modules + php_custom_modules | d([]) }}"
  children:
    backoffice:
      vars:
        php_custom_modules:
          - php82-php-bcmath
      hosts:
        backoffice1:
          ansible_host: 10.1.1.2
        backoffice2:
          ansible_host: 10.1.1.3

    webserver:
      vars:
        php_custom_modules:
          - php82-php-amqp
      hosts:
        webserver1:
          ansible_host: 10.1.1.4
        webserver2:
          ansible_host: 10.1.1.5
```

For the second point, the [notes in the`yum` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#notes) state:

> When used with a loop: each package will be processed individually, it is much more efficient to pass the list directly to the name option.

Applying this advice leads to the following example playbook:

```yaml
- name: Install PHP modules
  hosts: all
  
  tasks:
    - name: Install PHP modules
      ansible.builtin.yum: 
        name: "{{ php_modules }}" 
        state: present 
        enablerepo: remi-php82,remi-safe,epel
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your requirement is to have a different set of PHP modules per hosts groups, the best would be to attach your variable onto the groups, in your inventory.

For example:

```yaml
all:
  children:
    backoffice:
      vars:
        php_modules:
          - php82
          - php82-php-fpm
          - php82-php-bcmath
      hosts:
        backoffice1:
          ansible_host: 10.1.1.2
        backoffice2:
          ansible_host: 10.1.1.3

    webserver:
      vars:
        php_modules:
          - php82
          - php82-php-fpm
          - php82-php-amqp
      hosts:
        webserver1:
          ansible_host: 10.1.1.4
        webserver2:
          ansible_host: 10.1.1.5
```

Then your playbook simplifies to:

```yaml
- name: Install PHP modules
  hosts: all
  
  tasks:
    - name: Install PHP modules
      yum: 
        name: "{{ item }}" 
        state: present 
        enablerepo: remi-php82,remi-safe,epel
      loop: "{{ php_modules }}"
```